# Is Akamaru a pet or a comrade?

Tags: naruto

My question is if Akamaru is a pet or a comrade to Kiba. I'm wondering this because he fights alongside Kiba and Kiba treats him like he was another human being (most of the time), but at the same time he also treats him like a pet.

Examples and or clues that he's a pet:

1. Teaches him tricks
2. Takes baths with him (not a lot of people do but a lot of little kids do)
3. Calls him "boy" (Like, "Here boy!")
4. He was given to Kiba at a very young age by Kiba's mother (something that happens a lot in real life)
5. They lived together for (you could say) their whole life so they're like family (something that also happens in real life)
6. They play together (something you will do with a friend or pet)
7. Kiba cares a lot about Akamaru that he will do anything to protect him (something that a lot of people do for their pets)

The list goes on and on. I've been looking up stuff, but haven't found anything that says he's his pet. It only says he's his partner, comrade, friend, etc.

When I look up, "Kiba and his pet", then go to images, it shows (at least the first couple of pictures) Kiba and Akamaru.

So is Akamaru Kiba's pet or comrade? To better put it, is Akamaru a pet or a comrade to Kiba?

Comment: why not both pet and comrade?

Comment: @MichaelMcQuade he could be both, but I'm wondering if he is a pet or a comrade to Kiba.

Comment: The meaning for pet and companion is pretty close but since his dog is with him from his childhood then I guess it already become a part of his life. So I guess he treats him like a comrade who works together and treats him like a pet at home when he needs care or attention. Even in naruto shippuden episode there was one event in fillers when kiba dream that he has become hokage and he announced that there must be one dog day and everyone must own one dog. Since they cant buy comrade (talented dogs) so he might be indicating to own one pet dog.

Comment: `He is Kiba Inuzuka's partner, as well as his best friend and companion` - [Naruto Wikia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Akamaru)

Comment: Akamaru is a Ninja Tool no matter how cruel that sound. If he is a pet/comrade then Kiba won't be allowed to use him in Chuunin Exam . . .

Comment: What about after the first few images? kekeke

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this will depend on how you define a pet and comrade, dictionary.com defines a pet as any domesticated or tamed animal that is kept as a companion and cared for affectionately. And it defines a comrade as a companion who shares one's activities or is a fellow member of an organization/a fellow soldier or member of the armed services.

By the first definition he could be considered a pet, though he is clearly more than that. The entire clan use collaboration techniques with their canine companions, drawing strength from their combined and coordinated techniques; they have a symbiotic relationship on and off the battlefield, protecting each other and playing together, as well as fighting fiercely together.

In the real world hunting dogs are probably the closest comparison we have to the battlefield interactions we see between the Inuzuka clan and their companion animals. Training a hunting dog requires asserting yourself as an alpha in their pack, and maintaining that controlling position constantly. Treating a hunting dog as a pet as well frequently blurs the lines on what behavior is and is not allowed from the animal and can undermine its hunting training. 
https://www.southernstates.com/articles/training-hunting-dogs.aspx

In the case of the Inuzuka clan we see more than just a working relationship that leads to optimal performance of hunting dogs. Akamaru makes suggestions during fights. He even bites Kiba in the fight against Sakon and Ukon insisting that they use a risky technique. This clearly indicates that Kiba is not an alpha to be obeyed regardless of circumstances and they have a more equal relationship more akin to sworn brothers.

In conclusion, Akamaru is more than just a pet and its probably most accurate to call them true partners.

Answer (score 1):

Is Akamaru a pet or a comrade?

That's the question and my answer to that...

Well in my limited knowledge about it I say that Akamaru is not just a pet to Kiba, but more as a comrade/friend/family. When you watch Naruto, in some of their scenes you will see no pet-to-master relationship but a bond of friendship between them like comrades. You will see that Kiba treats Akamaru more than just a dog or a pet, but treats it like a comrade that he wants to protect and cherish... ^__^