# Why do akamaru gets angry at stuff?

Tags: naruto, anime-production

Whenever kiba gets angry about something being said, akamaru (his hound) also gets angry. Do akamaru understand those complex things being said?

Comment: Some related questions: https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4161/why-cant-inuzuka-clans-dogs-use-human-language?rq=1 .. https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/30821/is-akamaru-a-pet-or-a-comrade?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't Inuzuka clan's dogs use human language?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4161/why-cant-inuzuka-clans-dogs-use-human-language)

Answer (score 1):

Akamaru is loyal ninja hound and Kiba is his best friend, both of them often share each others emotions. He can also understand human language that makes him more reliable.
You can read more about [Akamaru here](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Akamaru)